# $x^x = y$, express $x$ in terms of $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^x = y$

Express $x$ in terms of $y$.

I'm particularly interested in the solution where $x$ is real, but complex would be interesting too.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: $x$ in terms of $y$ is not a valid function. It would be a correspondence.

Comment: Thank you, Erik.

Is there a trivial way of showing it is not a valid function?

(Also, is it not a function in the sense that there may be multiple values of $x$ for certain values of $y$, or in some other sense?)

Comment: I'm surprised it is not a valid function. The graph in Wolfram Alpha looks like it could be.

[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex+%3D+y)

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the reason (there exists a $y$ that more than one $x$ value can generate). Odd, it seems Wolfram Alpha is sensitive to the order in which you enter the equation, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20x%5Ex

Comment: Whenever you see a $x^x$, think of  [Lambert's $\mathrm W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 6):

Use [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

In mathematics, the Lambert W function, also called the omega function or product logarithm, is a set of functions, namely the branches of the inverse relation of the function $z = f(W) = We^W$ where $e^W$ is the exponential function and $W$ is any complex number. In other words, the defining equation for $W(z)$ is

$$z = W(z)e^{W(z)}$$

for any complex number $z$.

$\hskip1in$ [image]
${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$ ${ }$

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote you up. I hope others will.

Comment: @MysteriousEntity You're welcome and welcome to Math.StackExchange as well..